# Google Maps Api v3, dynamic zoom level when using places library

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a (rather large) JSON array of object which each contains a Latitude and a Longitude value. When my Google Map loads, I loop through this array and create a new marker which is added to the map.

Added to that, I'm using the Google Maps Api v3 Places plugin (pretty much out of the box from this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

When I search for a given address, I need to make sure that at least N number of my markers are visible on the map. Right now, I've set the zoom level to 10 at all times. However, when I search for i.e. Faroe Islands (where there's about 5 markers), the zoom level is too close and none of the 5 markers are visible to the user.

Is there any way of dynamically setting the zoom level so that at least 4 or 5 markers are visible to the user? :-)

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = null;
        var markers = [];
        var overlays = [];

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Init google map (API v. 3)
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.161, 10.77),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Create a new marker
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude),
                map: map,
                title: data[i].Name
            });

            // Add the marker to a global array for filtering
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

        // [START region_getplaces]
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
        // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                if (markers[i].type == "userMarker") {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
            }

            // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });

                marker.type = "userMarker";
                markers.push(marker);

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);                    
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setZoom(11);
        });
        // [END region_getplaces]

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
        // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();               
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
        });
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Once the map has finished zooming, get the map bounds, count the markers on the map contained in the bounds, if it is less than your desired threshold zoom out until it is.  You should be able to calculate the bounds given the center of the map and the zoom level and do the same without needing the map to finish centering and zooming to the first location.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to ensure at least one marker is visible on landing on a map from a search or change of position etc. It only ensures ONE marker is in view and the current location of the user/search query (marker_location).

My array of markers is called mapMarkers[], I think looking at your code, you'll need to update that to markers.

It currently finds the closest marker to the center of the map (c) but you could update that to be another position.

Run setBounds() whenever you want to update.

Hopefully you'll be able to expand this to ensure however many markers you need are on the page. Each marker distance is stored in the distances[] array, so maybe do an array sort on that, a for loop and return an array of markers and bounds.extend on each of them??

```
function rad(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

var c = map.getCenter(),
lat = c.lat(),
lng = c.lng();

center_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

function find_closest_marker() {
    var R = 6371; // radius of earth in km
    var distances = [];
    var closest = -1;
    for( i=0; i<mapMarkers.length; i++ ) {
        var mlat = mapMarkers[i].position.lat();
        var mlng = mapMarkers[i].position.lng();
        var dLat  = rad(mlat - lat);
        var dLong = rad(mlng - lng);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.cos(rad(lat)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c;
        distances[i] = d;
        if ( closest == -1 || d < distances[closest] ) {
                closest = i;
        }
    }

    return mapMarkers[closest];
}

function setBounds(){
    var closestMarker = find_closest_marker();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(closestMarker.position);
    bounds.extend(center_location); 
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```